# How to print element tags in XML document using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Very much a beginner with XSL.  I'm trying transform 2 XML documents into a new XML document.  I can't seem to get the tags to print to the new document.  Only the content of the elements is printing.

XML

```
<books>
  <book>
    <name>Cat in the Hat</name>
    <author>Me</name>
    ...
    ...
  </book>
  ...
  ...
</book>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes" /> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:element name="books">
        <xsl:template match="books">
            <xsl:element name="book">
                <xsl:for-each select="book">
                    <xsl:element name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="author"><xsl:value-of select="author"/></xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT to XML file
   Cat in the Hat
   Me

I need the output to be:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <name>Cat in the Hat</name>
    <author>Me</author>
  </book>
</books>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the output you expect as actual XML, rather than a textual representation, please? Also, is it the case that you are just trying to show the `name` and `author` for each book in the output, and ignoring any other tags until the `book` element? Thanks!

Comment: Did you run this with an XSLT processor? The error message should be pretty easy to understand. `xsl:element` cannot be a top-level element.

Comment: I've added the expected output... which is the same as the input for now @TimC.

Comment: @MathiasMüller yes it has been run with an XSLT processor through eclipse.  Even if I remove the top-level element, I still get the same output.  I'm just not sure how to get the tags to display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you actually be getting an error when you run the output, as because MathiasMuller says in comments, `xsl:element` must not be a top-level element (i.e it cannot be a direct child of `xsl;stylesheet`). I am guessing Ecplise may just be ignoring that.

If you are, however, getting only text output, it is because of XSLT's [built-in template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) rules, which will be used to match nodes in the XML when there are not any matching templates in your XML. Effectively these will just skip over elements, and end up outputting any text nodes they find.

If you do want to start off with the same output as the input (which is actually a sensible approach if ultimately you wish only to only change part of the XML), you should start off with the [XSLT identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which on its own copies all nodes and attributes as-is (and will mean the built-in templates will not get used).

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Then, when you want to make changes to the output, you only need to write templates for the nodes/attributes you wish to change. For example, suppose you had a `date` element you wished to remove from under the `book` element, then you would just add this template

```
<xsl:template match="date" />
```

Or maybe you want to rename `name` to `title` then you would do this

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </title>
</xsl:template>
```

Note there is no real need to use `xsl:element` if you are just outputting a fixed element name.

Comment: + 1, perhaps you could add a few sentences on why all the text is output if there are no templates matching the input?

Comment: Good idea! I've added a couple of paragraphs to the start of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @TimC.  You've given a very clear answer which has helped me a lot to understand :)  Thanks you for going to so much effort.