# Combining 2 XML files into 1 using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble finding a suitable example to merge 2 XML files into 1, as per below:

movies.xml

```
<movies>
    <movie>
        <name>ET</name>
        <director>Steven Spielberg</director>
        <date>15 January 2000</date>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <name>The Neverending Story</name>
        <director>Steven Spielberg</director>
        <date>4 November 2006</date>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

directos.xml

```
<directors>
    <director>
        <name>Steven Spielberg</name>
        <age>55</age>
        <sex>male</sex>
    </director>
</directors>
```

required output:

```
<directors>
    <director>
        <name>Steven Spielberg</name>
        <age>55</age>
        <sex>male</sex>
        <movies>
            <movie>
                <name>ET</name>
                <date>15 January 2000</date>
            </movie>
            <movie>
                <name>The Neverending Story</name>
                <date>4 November 2006</date>
            <movie>
        </movies>
    </director>
</directors>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes" /> 

    <xsl:variable name="movieFile" select="document('movies.xml')" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="$movieFile/movies/movie/director">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At the moment, it is printing the whole director list within each movie group.

Can somebody please give me some guidance?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document

Comment: Show us the XSLT code you've tried so far and we'll be happy to help you debug it, but SO won't write the whole thing for you.

Comment: I've added some code @IanRoberts.  I wasn't expecting anybody to write the whole thing.  Was hoping for a nudge in the right direction :)

Comment: Before asking new questions, accept or otherwise respond to the [answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28669998/1987598).

Comment: I think, you could add a template for directors/director, which gets filtered movies from $movieFile.

Comment: This is a lookup problem, and the correct solution is to use a **key**. The exact implementation depends on whether you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Please make it a habit to indicate your version when asking an XSLT question.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace your second template with this one, and feed the 'directors.xml' file as input it should work:

```
<xsl:template match="director">
    <xsl:variable name="director-name" select="name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('movies.xml')/movies/movie[director=$director-name]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You copy each node using the identity template except the `director` node above, in which you add the matching contents of the `movie` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you can indeed use XSLT 2.0, then this could be quite simple:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="movieFile" select="document('movies.xml')" />

<xsl:key name="movie-by-director" match="movie" use="director" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="director">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <movies>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('movie-by-director', name, $movieFile)" />
        </movies>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I added another director and movie.  It doesn't compile @michael.hor257k

Comment: @CocaCola I don't know what you mean by "doesn't compile". Why don't you provide your actual (new) example and the exact result your get?